# d.TGA creating error

Tags: blend-modes

I am quite new to Blender here as I'm making Fortnite, scenes and more to earn a bit of extra cash.

As I had found out, to make custom skins (color replacement tool in Photoshop) i need the d.tga, as that is what I am replacing in the *Shading* taskbar in Blender, as I tried to extract it by clicking the *Open Image* button (2 folders). It keeps giving me this error (yellow marked in the picture):

[image]

As I'm still new to blender I've been searching everywhere I could, but no one has been using Blender for Fortnite thumbnails and had this problem, 
here is a short explanation, what i am wanting to do is go to the shading option and press this button sorry for the imgur link 
imgur.com/a/ja2BE2B
 When i go there it gives me a few options :
imgur.com/a/WnsYYUN 
I press the "use file from current directory" As that will unpack the d.tga from the skin and put it in my library where i can put that in Ps, it gives me and error when i try to do so which is my problem, if this didnt clear it up im sorry for my poor explanation (english isnt my first language)

Comment: Could you make your title and description more clear? This is a Blender forum, not Fortnite so people here are not necessarely familiar with what is required to 'make custom Fortnite skins'. You need to describe in more details what you're trying to achieve with Blender, including the steps to recreate your issue.

Comment: Ah yes ofcourse, so here is a short explanation, 
what i am wanting to do is go to the shading option and press this button sorry for the imgur link couldnt find out how to add a image to a comment https://imgur.com/a/ja2BE2B
When i go there it gives me a few options 
https://imgur.com/a/WnsYYUN
I press the "use file from current directory" As that will unpack the d.tga from the skin and put it in my library where i can put that in Ps, it gives me and error when i try to do so which is my problem, if this didnt clear it up im sorry for my poor explanation (english isnt my first language)

Comment: OK, that's great. Now please, edit your initial question and put this detail in along with the screenshots which you can embed using the same mechanism as your first image. It will be easier for other reader to understand your problem rather than reading the comments.